# ngrok connections line meaning

Tags: networking, ssh, ngrok

I have just set up ngrok, and read through the parts of the documentation pertaining to ssh, which is what I am using it for.

On the "host" or "server" device (not sure of the correct name), it shows a text UI, with a line for "Connections", with multiple columns. The columns are labelled "ttl" "opn" "rt1" "rt5" "p50" and "p90". There are numbers under each, which change occasionally.

I wish to know what each of the columns mean, as I have made many searches for "ngrok" and the labels, but nothing conclusive has come up in terms of their meanings.

Can anyone tell me what each of the labels mean?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, you can post your question over on [sf] where system and network administrators help people.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry, new to posting here.